# Manipulação de String em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, datetime, time, replace

Estou com o seguinte código

```
var wcalcAlm = ('0140')
alert(wcalcAlm)
//retorno esperado ('01:40')
```

Preciso que depois da 2 posição da variável `wcalcAlm` seja incluído `:`, assim tendo o seguinte retorno `01:40`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basta fazer o seguinte:

```js
function adicionarTexto(str, caracter, indice){
  return str.slice(0, indice) + caracter + str.slice(indice)
}

var wcalcAlm = ('0140')
console.log(adicionarTexto(wcalcAlm, ':', 2))
```

Isso adicionar um caracter (ou uma string) a partir do índice que você enviar.

Comment: Obrigado Felipe Avelar.

Answer (score 4):

Tem essa solução:

```
wcalcAlm.replace(/(\d{2})/,'$1:');
```

- `replace` vai percorrer o valor todo.
- `/(\d{2})/` com o RegEx vou pegar os dígitos e quebrar na segunda posição.
- depois de ter separado ele cria uma máscara depois do primeiro grupo, com o caractere `:`.
- e reuni da maneira esperada.

```js
var wcalcAlm = ('0140');
console.log(wcalcAlm.replace(/(\d{2})/,'$1:'));
```

Answer (score 2):

**Outra forma:**

```js
//Duas linhas:
var wcalcAlm = ('0140').split("");
console.log(wcalcAlm[0] + wcalcAlm[1] + ":" + wcalcAlm[2] + wcalcAlm[3]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Vou colocar mais duas opções de como podemos chegar no resultado desejado:

```js
//Opção com array
const arr = '0140'.split('');
arr.splice(2,0,':');

console.log(arr.join(''));

//Opção com regex
let i = 0;
console.log('##:##'.replace(/#/g, () => '0140'[i++]));
```